# How to test useRef with the "current" prop in jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I hope someone can point me in the right direction to test `useRef` in the component below.

I have a component structured something like below. I am trying to test the functionality within the `otherFunction()` but I'm not sure how to mock the current property that comes off the component ref. Has anyone done something like this before?

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const thisComponent = useRef(null);
    const otherFunction = ({ current, previousSibling  }) => {
        if (previousSibling) return previousSibling.focus();
        if (!previousSibling && current) return current.focus();
    } 
    const handleFocus = () => {
        const {current} = thisComponent;
        otherFunction(current);
    }
     return (
        <div ref={thisComponent} onFocus={handleFocus}>Stuff In here</div>
    );
};
```

Comment: there is definitely no way to inject/modify function's closures(and `thisComponent` is available through closures in `handleFocus`). if `.focus()` is called properly to you(I mean there is no error) you may try to put mock on `HTMLElement.prototype.focus`

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 11):

Here is my test strategy for your case. I use `jest.spyOn` method to spy on `React.useRef` hook. It will let us mock the different return value of ref object for SFC.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { RefObject } from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';

export const Component = props => {
  const thisComponent: RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null);
  const otherFunction = ({ current, previousSibling }) => {
    if (previousSibling) return previousSibling.focus();
    if (!previousSibling && current) return current.focus();
  };
  const handleFocus = () => {
    const { current } = thisComponent;
    const previousSibling = current ? current.previousSibling : null;
    otherFunction({ current, previousSibling });
  };
  return (
    <div ref={thisComponent} onFocus={handleFocus}>
      Stuff In here
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('Component', () => {
  const focus = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('should render correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component></Component>);
    const div = wrapper.find('div');
    expect(div.text()).toBe('Stuff In here');
  });
  test('should handle click event correctly when previousSibling does not exist', () => {
    const useRefSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValueOnce({ current: { focus } });
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component></Component>);
    wrapper.find('div').simulate('focus');
    expect(useRefSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(focus).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should render and handle click event correctly when previousSibling exists', () => {
    const useRefSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValueOnce({ current: { previousSibling: { focus } } });
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component></Component>);
    wrapper.find('div').simulate('focus');
    expect(useRefSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(focus).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should render and handle click event correctly when current does not exist', () => {
    const useRefSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValueOnce({ current: null });
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component></Component>);
    wrapper.find('div').simulate('focus');
    expect(useRefSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(focus).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56739670/index.spec.tsx (6.528s)
  Component
    ✓ should render correctly (10ms)
    ✓ should handle click event correctly when previousSibling does not exist (3ms)
    ✓ should render and handle click event correctly when previousSibling exists (1ms)
    ✓ should render and handle click event correctly when current does not exist (2ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.689s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56739670

Comment: NOTE: this only works when using `const ref = React.useRef(..)` as opposed to `const ref = useRef(..)` as of jest 24.9.

Comment: It's not working for me. It is still calling the action function. Same happens for useContext. Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @ShivangGupta I had given the source code, you can check it. If you have a new question, please create a new question and provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code.

Comment: @ShivangGupta check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61789113/6463558

Comment: @slideshowp2 i have a similiar problem , i am trying to test an onClick on the div with a hidden file input having the 'ref' `<> <input type="file"    ref={hiddenFileInputRef}
                onChange={handleChange}
                style={{display: 'none'}}
            />
            <div
                onClick={handleClick}
                className="upload-button-container"></>` . i am getting " cannot read property of null " on simulating click. How to solve it ?

Comment: @roma Please ask a new question.

Comment: In reference to a comment above, about the `spyOn` not working if you are using `const ref = useRef(..)`. If you import React into your test file as `import * as React from "react"` the `spyOn` will work.