# Mock React useRef or a function inside a functional component with enzyme and jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

Codesanbox **[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-based-on-parents-element-size-xs0fe?file=/src/Child2.js)** - **includes working component Child2.js and working test Child2.test.js**

**Child2.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function Child2() {
  const divRef = useRef();

  function getDivWidth() {
    if (divRef.current) {
      console.log(divRef.current);
    }
    return divRef.current ? divRef.current.offsetWidth : "";
  }

  function getDivText() {
    const divWidth = getDivWidth();

    if (divWidth) {
      if (divWidth > 100) {
        return "ABC";
      }
      return "123";
    }

    return "123";
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id="myDiv" ref={divRef}>
        {getDivText()}
      </div>
      <p>Div width is: {getDivWidth()}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Child2.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Child2 from "../src/Child2";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it("div text is ABC when div width is more then 100 ", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Child2 />);
  expect(wrapper.find("#myDiv").exists()).toBe(true);
  expect(wrapper.find("#myDiv").text()).toBe("ABC");
});

it("div text is 123 when div width is less then 100 ", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Child2 />);
  expect(wrapper.find("#myDiv").exists()).toBe(true);
  expect(wrapper.find("#myDiv").text()).toBe("123");
});
```

When i run the tests, obvisouly the offsetWidth of the div is 0, hence i need to find a way to mock the `useRef` to return a div element with width or mock the `getDivWidth` function to return a desired number for the width.

How could I achieve that? I have searched for a solution, but I am stuck. There are some examples with class components or using typescript which I have not managed to use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) APIs to mock `useRef` hook except others. Which means other functions and methods of `react` are still original version.

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Child2() {
  const divRef = useRef();

  function getDivWidth() {
    if (divRef.current) {
      console.log(divRef.current);
    }
    return divRef.current ? divRef.current.offsetWidth : '';
  }

  function getDivText() {
    const divWidth = getDivWidth();

    if (divWidth) {
      if (divWidth > 100) {
        return 'ABC';
      }
      return '123';
    }

    return '123';
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id="myDiv" ref={divRef}>
        {getDivText()}
      </div>
      <p>Div width is: {getDivWidth()}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Child2 from './';

jest.mock('react', () => {
  const originReact = jest.requireActual('react');
  const mUseRef = jest.fn();
  return {
    ...originReact,
    useRef: mUseRef,
  };
});

describe('61782695', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mRef = { current: { offsetWidth: 100 } };
    useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child2></Child2>);
    expect(wrapper.find('#myDiv').text()).toBe('123');
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Div width is: 100');
  });

  it('should pass - 2', () => {
    const mRef = { current: { offsetWidth: 300 } };
    useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child2></Child2>);
    expect(wrapper.find('#myDiv').text()).toBe('ABC');
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Div width is: 300');
  });

  it('should pass - 3', () => {
    const mRef = {};
    useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Child2></Child2>);
    expect(wrapper.find('#myDiv').text()).toBe('123');
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Div width is: ');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61782695/index.test.jsx (9.755s)
  61782695
    ✓ should pass (111ms)
    ✓ should pass - 2 (15ms)
    ✓ should pass - 3 (1ms)

  console.log
    { offsetWidth: 100 }

      at getDivWidth (stackoverflow/61782695/index.jsx:8:15)

  console.log
    { offsetWidth: 100 }

      at getDivWidth (stackoverflow/61782695/index.jsx:8:15)

  console.log
    { offsetWidth: 300 }

      at getDivWidth (stackoverflow/61782695/index.jsx:8:15)

  console.log
    { offsetWidth: 300 }

      at getDivWidth (stackoverflow/61782695/index.jsx:8:15)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.885s
```

package versions:

```js
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
"jest": "^25.5.4",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works and saved me from lots of headache. To ask you another question, if I add inside my component a `useLayoutEffect` which will read use the `divref.current.childNodes` to get widths of all the `li` elements, how would I change the tests? I tried it and my in the test it never goes inside the function inside the `useLayoutEffect`. In real-life situation I have this scenario, on first render the component has no refs, on second render i have refs and then i use that metadata for operations inside the component.

Comment: @VergilC. You need to ask a new question

Comment: I'll getting this typescript error -> `Error:(397, 21) TS2339: Property 'mockReturnValueOnce' does not exist on type '<T>() => RefObject<T>'.`
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @ChristianSaiki mock React and its types and then use useRef from that. `const mockedReact = React as jest.Mocked<typeof React>;` and then `mockedReact.useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);`

Comment: @MantasAstra Im receiving the error `mockedReact.useRef.mockReturnValueOnce is not a function` any idea?

Comment: This works only on the root of the component, but the ref is still undefined inside useEffect, any way to solve this?

Comment: Use chaining to mock multiple refs in a single component.
`mockedReact.useRef.mockReturnValueOnce(imgRef).mockReturnValueOnce(parentRef).mockReturnValueOnce(captionRef)`
Note: order of mocking ref should be same in order as in the component